# Reconstructed Image after Laplacian Pyramid Not the same as original image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am converting an RGB image into YCbCr and then want to compute the laplacian pyramid for the same. After color conversion, I am experimenting with the code give on the Image Pyramid tutorial of OpenCV to find the Laplacian pyramid of an image and then reconstruct the original image. However, if I increase the number of levels in my code to a higher number, say 10, then the reconstructed image(after conversion back to RGB) does not look the same as the original image(image looks blurred - please see below link for the exact image). I am not sure why this is happening. Is it suppose to happen when the levels increase or is there anything wrong in the code?

```
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame_RGB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
height = 10
Gauss = frame.copy()
gpA = [Gauss]
for i in xrange(height):
    Gauss = cv2.pyrDown(Gauss)
    gpA.append(Gauss)

lbImage = [gpA[height-1]]

for j in xrange(height-1,0,-1):
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpA[j])
    L = cv2.subtract(gpA[j-1],GE)
    lbImage.append(L)

ls_ = lbImage[0]     
for j in range(1,height,1):
    ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_)
    ls_ = cv2.add(ls_,lbImage[j])

ls_ = cv2.cvtColor(ls_, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)                
cv2.imshow("Pyramid reconstructed Image",ls_)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For reference, please see the reconstructed image and the original image.

[Reconstructed Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ24NxgWWuxZFRadmZ6UUdRb2s/view?usp=sharing)

[Original Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ24NxgWWuxYURIYk1rclBDeU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: why do you create the laplacian pyramid? are you using it for something? why don't you just use the original image?

Comment: I want to perform temporal filtering for which I need a laplacian decomposition. After filtering, I need to add the filtered output to the original Image(which I have, don't need pyramid reconstruction for that). Now my question is that if I am not able to get a good original Image from the pyramid then the temporal filtering I perform will also not be correct. Hence I need a method which can give me a pyramid in such a way that I can perform filtering properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyrDown blurs an image and downsamples it, loosing some information. Saved pyramid levels (`gpA[]` here) contain smaller and smaller image matrices, but don't keep rejected information details (high-frequency ones).

So reconstructed image cannot show all original details

From tutorial:
[Note: When we reduce the size of an image, we are actually losing information of the image.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there anyway by which I can reconstruct the original image?

Comment: To reconstruct the image perfectly, you have to save also difference between resampled (pyrdown+pyrup) image at every level. But it will spend a lot of memory, so storing original image would be better. What is your main goal?

Comment: I have found a way to get a better Image from the pyramid. In the above code I was doing cv2.subtract() at each step. Instead subtract images normally like img1 - img2(where img2 is the gaussian image of img1) for height-1 levels and then finally use cv2.subtract for the last level. This will not clip values after subtraction at each level to 0(if they give a negative value), instead will do it once only at last level. For that I had to first convert the image to int16 first. Same can be done for cv2.add() function. It seems to be working fine. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `np.add()` or `np.substract()`. They perform a clipping. Use the direct - and + matrix operator. In other words, use:

```
L = gpA[j-1] - GE
```

Instead of:

```
L = cv2.subtract(gpA[j-1],GE)
```

Comment: this should be an accepted answer

Comment: also, perform these calculations in 16 or 32 bit. 8 bit calculations give precision errors.
and yes this should be accepted answer