# Python cv2 Image Pyramids

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

Trying to implement the famous Orange/Apple pyramids blending ([cv2 Image Pyramids](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_pyramids/py_pyramids.html)).

Note: Both images shape is 307x307.

However, since the result image is blurred due to clipping values in `cv2.subtract` and `cv2.add` (as stated in [cv2 vs numpy Matrix Arithmetics](http://opencvpython.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/difference-between-matrix-arithmetic-in.html)), I have used `numpy` arithmetics instead as suggested in [StackOverflow: Reconstructed Image after Laplacian Pyramid Not the same as original image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498713/reconstructed-image-after-laplacian-pyramid-not-the-same-as-original-image).

I have tested this by performing pyramids on one image and the result image constructed back using pyramids has the same Max,Min,Average pixels values as opposed to using `cv2` arithmetics.

However, on pyramids level 7, the result image gets a 'noise' of a red dot and on level 9 the result image gets a lot of green pixels noises. [Images of levels 6, 7, 9 - Imgur Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV6XJ.jpg).

Any ideas why would this happen? The pyramid level 9 green noise I would say happened because the image went below 1x1 shape. But what about the red dot on 7 level pyramid?

- EDIT : Code Added

  ```
  numberOfPyramids = 9

  # generate Gaussian pyramids for A and B Images
  GA = A.copy()
  GB = B.copy()
  gpA = [GA]
  gpB = [GB]

  for i in xrange(numberOfPyramids):
      GA = cv2.pyrDown(GA)
      GB = cv2.pyrDown(GB)
      gpA.append(GA)
      gpB.append(GB)

  # generate Laplacian Pyramids for A and B Images
  lpA = [gpA[numberOfPyramids - 1]]
  lpB = [gpB[numberOfPyramids - 1]]

  for i in xrange(numberOfPyramids - 1, 0, -1):
      geA = cv2.pyrUp(gpA[i], dstsize = np.shape(gpA[i-1])[:2]) 
      geB = cv2.pyrUp(gpB[i], dstsize = np.shape(gpB[i-1])[:2])

      laplacianA = gpA[i - 1] - geA if i != 1 else cv2.subtract(gpA[i-1], geA)
      laplacianB = gpB[i - 1] - geB if i != 1 else cv2.subtract(gpB[i-1], geB)

      lpA.append(laplacianA)
      lpB.append(laplacianB)

  # Now add left and right halves of images in each level
  LS = []
  for la, lb in zip(lpA, lpB):
      _, cols, _ = la.shape
      ls = np.hstack((la[:, : cols / 2], lb[:, cols / 2 :]))
      LS.append(ls)

  # now reconstruct
  ls_ = LS[0]
  for i in xrange(1, numberOfPyramids):
      ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_, dstsize = np.shape(LS[i])[:2])
      ls_ = ls_ + LS[i] if i != numberOfPyramids - 1 else cv2.add(ls_, LS[i])

  cv2.imshow(namedWindowName, ls_)
  cv2.waitKey()
  ```

Comment: What is the data type of the arrays that you are using?  (If `img` is the numpy array, check `img.dtype`.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Both images types are `numpy.ndarray` and the data type is `uint8`.

Comment: Check for overflow of the 8 bit values in your arrays.  But without seeing actual code (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I don't think we can help much more.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Added the code that reproduces the results

Answer (score 1):

After read the original [article](http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/adelson/pub_pdfs/pyramid83.pdf) about laplacian pyramid, I find I misunderstood this method, we can fully reconstruct the original image without blur, because we use of additional pix information. And It is true that clipping value lead to blurred. Well now we come back to the beginning again :)

So the code you post is still clipping value, I advise you use int16 to save the laplacian pyramid, and not use cv2.subtract. Hope it works.

Comment: Would you be kind enough with providing me one of those articles? I could not find any articles containing that kind of information...

Comment: Well, if you have enough patience, you can read the original article: [link](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/RCA84.pdf). The topic about low resolution image reconstruction, you can search "super resolution" in google scholar.

Comment: After I read the article, I find the laplacian pyramid has negative value. And we can fully reconstruct the image using laplacian pyramid, so I update my answer.@Elia

Comment: Tried working with uint16, int16, float32 and only at the end, when displaying the image, changing it to uint8 and still getting same results. @very hit